# In Xcode 10 .xcscheme changes automatically

Tags: ios, git, atlassian-sourcetree, xcode10

I am getting these changes after updating the Xcode 9.x to Xcode 10. while committing in Sourcetree.

Will be there any issue if I commit these changes?

[image]

Comment: Issue in regards to what?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, language = "" has been removed will be any issue if commit.

Comment: So this is an Xcode question not a git question?